# fbchat module in Python - can't get message to send

Tags: python, facebook

I am trying to send Facebook messages using a bot. Here is the code I have so far.

```
import fbchat
from fbchat import Client
from fbchat import models

client = Client('my_facebook_username', 'my_facebook_password')

Client.send(message='a', thread_id='tom.dry.18', 
thread_type=models.ThreadType.USER)
```

And this is the error message I get:

```
Client.send(message='a', thread_id='tom.dry.18', 
thread_type=models.ThreadType.USER)

TypeError: send() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

How can I proceed?

Comment: I don't write Python, but the error message seems self-explanatory to me - you are missing a required argument. Is there a published API for this module online?

Answer (score 1):

python is case-sensitive

```
Client.send(message='a', thread_id='tom.dry.18', thread_type=models.ThreadType.USER)
```

should be

```
client.send(message='a', thread_id='tom.dry.18',  thread_type=models.ThreadType.USER)
```

---

**A Not Very Technical Elaboration:**

The instance method `send` should be called from the client instance and not the client class.

Consider the following example

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    def bar(self, greeting):
        print('{} {}!'.format(greeting, self.name))
foo = Foo(name='foo')

foo.bar(greeting='hello')
# prints
hello foo!


Foo.bar(greeting=hello') # this is analogous to your bug
# outputs error traceback
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-23d058707a46> in <module>()
----> 1 Foo.bar(greeting='hello')

TypeError: bar() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

The first argument in instance methods accept an instance, and when called from the instance, are passed the instance implicitly.

For instance, in the above toy greeting application

```
Foo.bar(foo, greeting='hello')
# correctly prints out
hello foo!
```

When you write `foo.bar(greeting='hello')` it is equivalent to `Foo.bar(foo, greeting='hello')`

The first argument doesn't have to be called `self`, though that is a convention one should adhere to in python.

Consider:

```
class Foobar(object):
    def __init__(this, name):
        this.name = name
    def bar(me, greeting):
        print('{} {}!'.format(greeting, me.name))

foobar = Foobar('foobar')
foobar.bar(greeting='hello')
# prints
hello foobar
Foobar.bar(foobar, greeting='hello')
# also prints
hello foobar
```

**To avoid typos like above, avoid names that are different only in capitalization**

- *maybe consider `fb_client` instead of `client` as a name for the `Client` instance*
- *maybe enforce the rule throughout the codebase that instance names should not shadow their class names, i.e. `foo=Foo('foo')` should be considered bad*